# Django exclude users with same email

Tags: python, django

I have 2 user models in my django project. So it set up like this:
UserModel1 has 500 users with email
and UserModel2 has 2000 users with email.
And 300 users are both registered inn UserModel1 and UserModel2. So that means the two models share 300 users. UserModel1 has 200 excluding the users they both have in common, and UserModel2 has 1700 users exluded the users they have in common.

I wanted to make a query that gets all the useres from UserModel2 that are not registered in UserModel1. So i want to get the 1700 useres they dont have in common. After som research i landed on this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

not_matching = UserModel2.objects.filter(~Q((email__in=UserModel1.objects.values('email')))
```

but no luck, any ideas?

Comment: Hi, do you already tried to use exclude instead of filter? I believe that the problem is `email__in=UserModel1.objects.values('email')` returns a query not a list

Comment: yep, i get a empty queryset

Comment: I see... This `email__in=UserModel1.objects.values('email')` returns something like this `[{'email': 'email@...'}]` do you need a actual list of values instead of objects, i think this will fix the problem `[email.email for email in UserModel1.objects.values('email')]`

Comment: Try UserModel1.objects.values_list('email', flat=True)